# My LINQ sort does not seem to be sorting the way I asked it to

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
var query = _cityRepository.GetAll(
                              u => u.PartitionKey == pk &
                              u.RowKey.CompareTo(lowerBound) >= 0 &
                              u.RowKey.CompareTo(upperBound) < 0)
               .OrderBy(item => item.RowKey.Substring(0, 3))
               .ThenBy(item => item.ShortTitle)
               .Select((t, index) => new City.Grid()
               {
                   PartitionKey = t.PartitionKey,
                   RowKey = t.RowKey,
                   Row = index + 1,
                   ShortTitle = t.ShortTitle,
                   Created = t.Created,
                   CreatedBy = t.CreatedBy,
                   Modified = t.Modified,
                   ModifiedBy = t.ModifiedBy
               })
               .ToList();
```

When I look at the data coming out I find this for the first two rows:

```
RowKey = 0101004O , ShortTitle = "Access 1"
RowKey = 0103004M , ShortTitle = "Access 2"
RowKey = 0101004K , ShortTitle = "xxx"
```

When testing I simplified this to:

```
        var query1 = _cityRepository.GetAll()
            .OrderBy(item => item.RowKey.Substring(0, 3))
            .ThenBy(item => item.ShortTitle);
```

and the order is the same. Still the RowKey does not seem to be in the right order.

It is supposed to sort on the first four characters of the rowkey and then on the ShortTitle.

Can anyone see why this is not working. I have looked hard but I can't see why the OrderBy and ThenBy doesn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: The bug might be here: **item.RowKey.Substring(0, 3)**. I think it should be **item.RowKey.Substring(0, 4)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're sorting by the first 3 characters of `rowkey`, not 4.  To use 4 characters, do this:

```
     .OrderBy(item => item.RowKey.Substring(0, 4))
```

Comment: D'oh! I was about to post something silly about `Substring()` capturing a closure!

Comment: Thanks. I looked with google and saw something different for substring. I might have accidentally looked for java :-( I will mark your answer correct.

Answer (score 2):

`Substring`'s second parameter is `length`, not index, which I believe is what your code is attempting to do. Your code in its current state is sorting based on the first three characters. Change:

```
.OrderBy(item => item.RowKey.Substring(0, 3))
```

to

```
.OrderBy(item => item.RowKey.Substring(0, 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your substring to Substring(0, 4) if you want to get 4 chars. 2nd parameter specifies length not the index